# Insight into one of Japan's regions which is called 中国

Tags: etymology

I was doing some research into the difference between Japanese states, regions, prefectures, etc. today when I noticed that one of the regions is called ちゅうごく (中国).

Is there a reason that one of the regions is given the same name as China ?

Comment: https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD%E5%9C%B0%E6%96%B9#%E6%A6%82%E8%A6%81 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%ABgoku_region#History

Answer (score 3):

The word 「中國」 is a [*kango*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kango) which literally means *middle* 「中」 *region* 「國」.

---

[「[國]{こく}」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=2021) ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_%282014%29): **/*[C.q]ʷˤək/**, *state* > *country*) is comprised of

- semantic 「囗」 (*picture of city walls* > *surround*, now written 「[圍]{囲}」)
- simultaneously semantic and phonetic  [「[或]{こく}」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=894), which is a *picture of*

  - *a* [*dagger-axe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger-axe) [「戈」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=127) guarding
  - *a region* represented by 「囗」(small centre-left square shape in 「或」) surrounded by *borders* (represented by horizontal lines「㇐」 above and beneath 「囗」).

「或」 thus represents the ancestral [morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme) of both 「國」 and 「[域]{よく}」 (**/*[ɢ]ʷrək/**, *area/region*), and 「國」 and 「域」 are [cognate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognate). If you can't stop seeing the word *China* in 「[中國地方]{ちゅうごくちほう}」, I suggest you mentally interpret it as 「中域地方」.

Since 「或」 originally represented the morpheme now written as 「國」, the word represented by 「中國」 was originally written as 「中或」. From 《尊》 ([《殷周金文集成》6014](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=6014)):

[image]

> [隹]{唯}[珷]{武}王旣[]{克}大邑商[]{則}【[⿺⿹人彡]{廷（筳）}】[]{告}【[⿰于弓]{于}】{{zh:天}}曰余[]{其}宅[]{兹}**[]{中}或**自[]{之}【[⿰]{乂}】【[⿸目十]{民}】
>
> *[For]{唯} [[King Wǔ]{武王}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Wu_of_Zhou) had [already]{旣} [[defeated]{克}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Muye) the [Great]{大} [State]{邑} of [[Shāng]{商}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang). He [thus]{則} conducted [ritual divination]{筳（筳篿）} and [prayed]{告} [to]{于} [[Heaven]{天}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tian), [saying]{曰}: "[I]{余} [shall]{其} [settle]{宅} in [these]{兹} [[central]{中} [regions]{或（國・域）}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhongyuan), and [govern]{乂} the [people]{民} [from]{自} [here]{之}."*

Please note that 「中或」 **doesn't mean China** (or the [Zhōu Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_dynasty) in this context), it means the *central regions* of the state/"nation"/"country". The meaning *China* for 「中國」 is a **Chinese-language** literary name, rather than a name used by the states surrounding China (such as Japan), until the formation of the Chinese Republics. The literary name comes from ancient Chinese Dynasties considering the ruling power controlling the Central Plain Regions as holding the [Mandate of Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandate_of_heaven).

Chinese dynasties usually referred to themselves and the predecessor dynasty with their *dynasty name* or *capital city name* (the above inscription referred to Shāng as 「大邑商」), rather than the literary name 「中國」.

---

According to Japanese and English Wikipedia, the exact origin of the name is unknown. However, 「中國」 in the context of 「中國地方」 should also be taken with a more literal meaning: *middle regions > middle provinces* (*koku*, provincial administrative division in Ancient Japan). Some relevant definitions from [*kotobank*](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9B%BD-97172):

> - 国の中央の部分。天子の都のある地方。
> - 律令制で、都からの距離によって国を遠国・中国・近国に分類したうちの一。
>
>   - This definition implies that the name 「中国」 may come from a *proximity relation from an administrative centre* (with other *far provinces* and *near provinces*).

Answer (score 2):

Being Chinese myself, I dont think these two meanings are connected in any way. Most likely just pure coincidence. Some evidence to consider:

1. The word goku in the chugoku actually does not mean "country", but means something closer to "region".
2. 中国 is actually abbreviation of 中华人民共和国（People's Republic of China), which did not exist until 1949. Although the word 中国 was used before 1949, as abbreviation of 中华民国，the predecessor of China, current government of taiwan.